# Display the post data after error in django and html5

Tags: django, html, django-forms, django-templates

django form

```
{% for field in form.fields %}
    {{field}}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

If there is an error `{{field.email}}` will output this html with a post data value

```
<input id="id_email" type="text" value="gffdg" />
```

I want to use HTML 5 inputs but don't know how to get the post value if there is error

```
<input id="id_email" type="email" >
```

edit..

I was hoping not to use widgets with my django forms and just type the html5 code in my template (type="email" not type="text")

```
<input id="id_email" type="email" >`
```

but can't figure out how to get the value back after a post with errors.

```
<input value="?????" />
```

Comment: Sorry dude but I dont understand what are u asking exactly (:

Comment: You might want to have a look at [django-html5-forms](https://github.com/adamcupial/django-html5-forms)?

Comment: Django can have html5 forms by changing the widget of the field, I just want an easy way of doing it with html, specially with model packages that I did not make like allauth models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the bound value of the email field, then the following template code should work:

```
<input id="id_email" type="email" value="{{ form.email.value }}">
```

If the value is not set, then it will be a blank field.

Comment: I am getting none on the input field if it's blank, anyway to make it a space? It happens when I click another link and goes back to link that has my form.

Comment: You can use the [default-if-none](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none) filter